Filter out directly registered metrics
Jmx_exporter has a list of directly registered metrics:

jmx_exporter
jmx_config
jmx_scrape
jvm_
process_

These are include even when using includeObjectNames to be explicit in what should be included. How can I filter out any of these metrics?
